# SharePoint list calculated column based on status in other columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, approval-process

I have a list built with three levels of approval on an item. I want to add a calculated column to quickly show the status of the item based on those approvals.

So if all three approvals exist, the calculated column would show "Complete". If all/any of the three approvals are missing, the column would show "In Progress".

The columns it is calculating off of are choice columns. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have 3 different choice columns for 3 levels of approval status?

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula in this format:

```
=IF(AND([1st Level Approval] = "Approved", [2nd Level Approval] = "Approved", [3rd Level Approval] = "Approved"), "Complete", "In Progress")
```

Use approval column names and their approval status values for all three level approvals as per your SharePoint site/list configurations.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`). For example: If you are using German language for your SharePoint site
2. Use correct *display* names of your columns in the formula

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with similar question to find the correct answer easily